# "Random" access to a large file in C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm recording video from a live stream. The format we're recording in requires the number of frames to be in the initial header. Obviously when we begin recording we don't know the size of the video and it can get into the 10s of GBs fairly easily. My question is, how does one overwrite a specific set of bytes in a binary file using C# without having to deal with the whole file?

Comment: what file format are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) - it will let you set the position in the file and overwrite at that location.

You will need to ensure at this point that the file is closed and no video is still being written to it as you could get a lock violation otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with videorecording, so dealing with very big files, ther is no other option then [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx).  If your logic is oriented on *seeking* the stream, it wouldn't be the easiest adoption in your code. But it would be, by the way, a best choice to make, imo.

A good example could be this one: [Programming Memory-Mapped Files with the .NET Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138290/Programming-Memory-Mapped-Files-with-the-NET-Frame)